# Where to define all of my constants / global variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have things like

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.test.com/"]];

KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"xyz" accessGroup:nil];
```

that I have to define in all of my files all the time. Is there a way I can define them in one file and just import it every time?

## edit

So as suggested I added this into my app delegate

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class AFHTTPClient;
@class KeychainItemWrapper;

@interface TestAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AFHTTPClient *httpClient;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem;
@end
```

and then tried to define my httpClient in my viewcontroller as

```
httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.test.com/"]];
```

it gives me an error saying `use of undeclared identifier 'httpClient'`

Comment: Take also a look at YourApp-Prefix.pch, which is a header for all source files

Comment: @Thorsten can you please elaborate a little more? how would that work?

Comment: Do you want to have the same `httpClient` instance in all files, or a new different instance for every file?

Comment: e.g. put this in your .pch-file and you can use it in all source files: #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

Comment: @Hejazi the same in every file

Comment: @Thorsten and what about my httpClient?

Comment: The recommended way is to use a singleton pattern and although this is not exactly what you are looking for, it is worth to check it out. "In HTTP client subclasses, create a class method that returns a shared singleton instance. This way, you can configure and use a single client to use throughout the entire app." -> AFNetworking-Guide: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

Comment: "A good example of an AFHTTPClient subclass can be found in the example project: AFAppDotNetAPIClient. Use it as a starting point for your own client." -> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches.  You could create a dedicated header file.  You could put categories on `AFHTTPClient` and `KeychainItemWrapper`.

I would probably just all of those into methods on my `AppDelegate`.  You don't have to import `AFHTTPClient.h` and `KeychainItemWrapper.h` in `AppDelegate.h` to do this.  You can just forward-declare the classes:

```
@class AFHTTPClient;
@class KeychainItemWrapper;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isIPhone5;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AFHTTPClient *httpClient;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem;

...
```

Then you just include `AFHTTPClient.h` and `KeychainItemWrapper.h` in the files that actually need to use those objects.

BTW, the comparison with `DBL_EPSILON` is pointless.  First, on iOS, `CGFloat` is an alias for `float`, not `double`.  You are needlessly converting to `double`.  Second, the `height` of the screen is 568.  A single-precision `float` can exactly represent every integer between -16777216 and 16777216, including 568.  You can just test for equality.

Comment: yeah I kind of figured :) I would rather go for Auto Layout. Thanks for the advise though. and where should I put all of them in my AppDelegate? wont I have to import all the headers associated with these files in the Delegate as well?

Comment: maybe I am still doing something wrong, but it still gives me error

Comment: It is hard to help you if you don't describe the error precisely.

Comment: You need to implement an `httpClient` method in `AppDelegate.m`, and access your app delegate's `httpClient` property in `ViewController.m`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you create a file with declared constants and import it every time :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made a global constants file in years… there is always a better, more localized place for such definitions. Still, such functionalities are useful -- will answer, but consider how you could declare these closer to implementations that need them.

- Create a header file and a source file
- Either declare C functions, or an ObjC class interface which has class methods.
- Define the functions/methods
- then `#import` the 'global constants' header only where needed (not in the PCH)

---

Example using C functions:

```
// MONApp_Constants.h
// no #imports up here

extern bool MONApp_Is_iPhone5(void);

@class AFHTTPClient;
extern AFHTTPClient * MONApp_HTTPClient(void);

@class KeychainItemWrapper;
extern KeychainItemWrapper * MONApp_KeychainItem(void);
```

Of course, you will need to find a good place to hold a reference to the objects, if you want only one instance. In that case, the functions should not be globally visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the global variables in a file called constants.h and import in other files where it is necessary.

I would suggest that you do no do this:

```
#define httpClient [[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.test.com/"]]];
```

The reason being URL that you are trying to request can vary. The idea for #define is to have for items that are constant. Even if you are always requesting from @"https://www.test.com/", I would still not recommend you to do that.

Hope this helps...